# FB login PHP - one page - 2 login buttons

Tags: php, facebook, authentication

I have one page and I need to have two facebook login buttons (using fb login php).

I need 2 scenarios:
1st button = login -> redirect on private cabinet
2nd button = login -> redirect on new article page.

When I try to use **$helper->getLoginUrl** twice with different **$redirectURL** for each link, only last works, and first gives error: 
"*Facebook SDK returned an error: Cross-site request forgery validation failed. The "state" param from the URL and session do not match.*"

```
$loginURL = $helper->getLoginUrl('site.com/', $fbPermissions);
$loginURL2 = $helper->getLoginUrl('site.com/new.php', $fbPermissions);
```

How to solve it?
Maybe I can transfer some parameter to know what button is pressed in GET request through FB-login url?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is due to the fact that `getLoginUrl` creates a new `state` value in the session on each call.

You have two options:

- call getLoginUrl once, take the result of that, and replace the value of the `redirect_uri` parameter using string functions. (Need to keep in mind that the value to replace has been URL-encoded.)
- dive a little bit deeper into the SDK, and call one of the lower-level methods that get used in the process. `getLoginURL` calls [`makeUrl`](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk/blob/2f9639c15ae043911f40ffe44080b32bac2c5280/src/Facebook/Helpers/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php#L123) - and in there the new state value is set, and afterwards `$this->oAuth2Client->getAuthorizationUrl` is called to finally create the login URL. So you could get the `state` value, that the first (and only) call to getLoginUrl set into the persistent data storage, and then call `getAuthorizationUrl` with that and the rest of the parameters, to create a different login URL, but that still uses the same state value.